# How to make cordova inappbrowser wait until iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

AFAIK, `addEventListener('loadstop', ...)`, one of InAppBrowser API, doesn't work with iframe.

I need to my script which is executed by `executeScript` wait until iframe is loaded. I agree that the term 'loaded' is ambigious, so it's okay to consider it as `onload` event of iframe element. But I have no idea how to register an event handler (inside executeScript) and retreiving the return value from it. Because `executeScript` passes the value of last statement to its callback, I think there is no way to pass it outside.

```
ref.executeScript({code:String.raw`
   document.iframe.addEventListener("load", function(){
       //How can I pass this outside executeScript?
       document.iframe.contentDocument.innerHTML
   })
`})
```

Then what is the proper way to wait until iframe is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by "polling" for the loaded value:

Once:

```
ref.executeScript({code:String.raw`
   window.iframeContent = null;
   document.iframe.addEventListener("load", function(){
       window.iframeContent = document.iframe.contentDocument.innerHTML;
   })
`})
```

Then Repeatedly call the following executeScript until you get a value (using setInterval or similar):

```
ref.executeScript({code:String.raw`
   return window.iframeContent;
`})
```